# Properties of Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for an example of ring epimorphism $\varphi:R\rightarrow S$ such that the natural homomorphism $\tilde\varphi:J(R)\rightarrow J(S)$ is not surjective, where $J(R)$ is a Jacobson radical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\varphi:Z\rightarrow Z_8; \quad \varphi(n)=\bar n $$
$J(Z)=0$. so $\varphi(J(Z))=0$  but $J(Z_8)= \langle 2 \rangle$